# Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I can't understand how this works in Android. I traversed samples and have no idea. For instance I need 2x2 grid view of TextView widgets. How to write needed code?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the android developer example, on how to create a GridView, to meet your requirements.

Here's the [full example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Also if your beginning Android [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224193) would be a good book for you.